# Unable to Execute REST API' StartWith for DateTime Column

Tags: rest, sharepoint-rest-api

I had written the below piece of REST API to filter the data for SharePoint DateTime Column , But I find no luck to execute

Also, When I use **startswith**
for SinglelieText column it's working fine. But for DateTime Column I am unable to crack

Can any one please do let me know what's wrong in it..

```
url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('OrderDetails')/items?$filter=(startswith(OrderDate,'3'))",
```

Comment: So what you're really looking for is filtering a datetime column by month?  Check [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/122210/20615) answer.

Answer (score 0):

**startswith** takes two parameters (string, string),

If you're trying to filter with date-time the items in specific month, you can use **month()** function  
because `/_api/web` endpoint does not support OData Date Time functions , as a workaround you can use `/_vti_bin/listdata.svc` end point which supports these functions

```
/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/OrderDetails?$filter=month(OrderDate)  eq 3
```

The above will return all items with `Orderdate` in March , 
Similar to this you can use :

**day()** or **year()** functions.

hope this will be helpful, please try and let me know.

Comment: I tired it Saeed, But I find no luck with Month() function sytax

Comment: @MSA what happened when you tried?  Did you get an error?  Incorrect results?

Comment: @MSA please check the updated answer